# How to pass an array index in a function & check in a function either this index is set or not php

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I have an associative array in php name as

```
$formData =array(
    "first"=>"John",
    "second"=>"George",
    "thirld"=>"Harry",
    "fourth"=>"Tom"
);
```

and a function called `isExist($v)` as

```
function isExist($v) {
    if(isset($v)) {
        return $v;
    } 
    return ""; 
}
```

now I want that this function check either array have index value set or not i.e if I call the function as

```
echo isExist($formData['apple']);
```

then it must print an empty string. How to achieve this?

Comment: needs more reading :) https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php

Answer (score 1):

There is no way you can achieve this with passing `$formData['apple']` you need to pass the array and index separately

```
function isExist($array,$index){
    if(isset($array[$index])){
    return $index;
   } 
  return ""; 
}
```

The error will be raised before it ever had the chance to get in the function because you already called it when you were passing it in as parameter. Use it like this instead

```
isExist($formData,'apple');
```

Comment: Of course I'm not sure what the advantage of this function is over just using `isset($array['key'])`...

Comment: I don't have a clue either I just answered the question that was asked by rizwan.ilyas

Comment: downvote because it's silly to re-implement core functions

Answer (score 0):

There is already such a function. It's called.... *drum roll*

> array_key_exists(string|int $key, array $array): bool
> array_key_exists() returns true if the given key is set in the array. key can be any value possible for an array index.

- https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php